# "perl.exe *32" not releasing memory when spawned by Apache 2.2 on Windows server 2008 64bit

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, 64-bit, perl

We have a web application that traditionally ran on Windows Server 2003 Std. Ed. 32bit in Apache2.2 with perl 5.8.  I am attempting to migrate it to a Windows Server 2008 Std. Ed. 64bit in Apache2.2 with perl 5.10 platform.  It ran great on the old platform, but now I am having memory issues.

In the httpd.conf I have:

> ```
> ThreadLimit 20
> ThreadsPerChild 20
> MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
> ```

In Windows Task Manager there are currently 20 instances of "perl.exe *32" using around 24,000K of memory a piece.  The number of instances grows or shrinks with the Thread Limit, but it never drops below the limit.  The application is technically up and running, but it is just very, very slow.   We are using the same httpd.conf in both platforms.  Could this be related to switching to perl 5.10, or switching to a 64bit version of windows, and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have

```
RequestHeader unset Connection
RequestHeader unset Server
```

set in your config file.  Remove those and the issue should go away.

Comment: That was it!  I commented out those lines and now it works.  How did you know?

Comment: My boss saw the issue once before and he told me about it.